# MAPAEL :plotting cities

Tags: plot, geocoding, mapael

I am using MAPAEL to plot cities onto an SVG map.
I understand the point of plotting 4 different points to 'transform' lat/long coordinates of a given city into x/y coordinates into the SVG, as explained by the plugin's author:  [here](https://www.vincentbroute.fr/mapael/create-map.php)

I am however confused about the last bit "***Then, you can use Google Maps in order to find the matching latitudes and longitudes and fill the form of the getCoords() generator.***":
How do I do this? Eg; get the x/y coordinates of all 4 points, from the SVG  'map' into a similar Google map to get the exact lat/ lon corresponding to these plots ?
I obviously need this missing bit of info to fill in the help form that writes up the JS ....
Many thanks,
JMB